# Regarding Highlighted Content Web Part with Carousel layout in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, modern-experience, web-partmodern-w

I am working with Highlighted Content Web Part in SharePoint online with modern template. when i select carousel to my show images in slider, the carousel is not showing images, but with any other layoutlike Cards, list and filmstrips are working fine. but that is not i require. Please help me two find the solution.  [image]

Thanks in Advance.
Please refer 2nd image which is my configuration.[image]

Comment: yes this was working fine a couple of weeks ago, and now suddenly images are not appearing... please Microsoft, sort this out ! thank you !